# Python package cannot be loaded into PBS queue file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pbs

The skopt package (https://scikit-optimize.github.io/stable/install.html) was installed on a cluster I use.

When I run the code in python directly in the terminal (i.e., cluster terminal), no problem occurs and the code works as expected.

However when I simply place the command to execute the code in a PBS queue system file (e.g., python3 ./code.py), I cannot load the installed package and I get the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "./test.py", line 22, in <module>
       from skopt import gp_minimize
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skopt'
```

Could someone give me an insight on how to solve the problem?

If I need to provide any more information, let me know.

ps1: the packages is installed on /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skopt directory.

ps2: I tried to load export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:[$HOME]/.usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skopt into the PBS file and it didn't work.

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct python you installed with, for example, you used "pip3 install skopt" use "python3 ./foo/bar.py", or vice versa "pip install skopt" use "python ./foo/bar.py"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was easier than I thought, as the skopt package was in the path "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/" just use the command "export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/ lib/python3.6/site-packages", before running the code in python

I was using the "export" command wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me before but its a pretty simple fix

```
pip3 converts to python3

pip converts to python
```

Use those commands instead of random. Check my comment for further details.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand very well. The command they used to install the package was actually "pip3 install skopt". But when I tried to run "python3 ./foo/bar.py" I got the following error message "python3: can't open file './foo/bar.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory", or running "python3 ./foo/test.py" i got python3: can't open file './foo/testelammps2.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: well yeah, because foo and bar were just placement items. You use your path to file. @EmersonPL